# How does "curl --retry-max-time <seconds>" work?

Tags: curl

I don't know how `--retry-max-time` calculated.
If I download a file `file.txt`:

```
curl --max-time 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 5 --retry-max-time 32 'http://www.site.com/download/file.txt'
```

---

- `[ 0- 2]` It takes `2s` to download `50%` of the file, and no speed any more.
- `[ 2-10]` It waits for another `8s`, still no speed, timeout, will retry
- `[10-15]` It waits for `5s` before retry #1
- `[15-25]` Still no speed, will retry
- `[25-30]` It waits for `5s` before retry #2
- `[30-34]` It takes `4s` to download `33%` of the file, and no speed any more.
- `[34-40]` It waits for another `6s`, still no speed, timeout

Will `curl` stop retry at this point(`40s`)?

When was the `retry timer` started and stopped?

---

```
   --retry-max-time <seconds>
          The  retry  timer  is reset before the first transfer attempt. Retries will be done as usual (see --retry) as
          long as the timer hasn't reached this given limit. Notice that if the timer hasn't  reached  the  limit,  the
          request  will be made and while performing, it may take longer than this given time period. To limit a single
          request´s maximum time, use -m, --max-time.  Set this option to  zero  to  not  timeout  retries.  (Added  in
          7.12.3)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let me try to clarify.

When curl decides to do a retry (because `--retry` is used and the conditions were such that a retry is warranted) and a `--retry-max-time` was set, curl checks if the total time elapsed since the start of the operation has surpassed the `--retry-max-time` or not. If it hasn't, it will allow another retry.

So in your command line above: if the total time is less than 32 seconds by the time it considers the retry, it will do another retry. If the total time is more than 32 seconds it will not do any more retries.

Answer (score 57):

```
curl --connect-timeout 5 \
     --max-time 10 \
     --retry 5 \
     --retry-delay 0 \
     --retry-max-time 60 \
     'http://www.site.com/download/file.txt'
```

---

```
|<---0---->| {<---1---->|  |<---2---->|    |<---3---->|   |<---4---->|   }            |<---5---->|
|....==    | {...==     |  |....==    |    |.....|        |..=== =   |   }
             {                                                           }
```

#### NOTATION

```
=====  downloading...       (file size is 5)
.....  --connect-timeout 5
|<->|  --max-time 10
<-5->  --retry 5
>| |<  --retry-delay 0      ([default] exp backoff algo)
{   }  --retry-max-time 60  (GAME OVER)
```

#### NOTE

- retry delay 1, 2, 4, 8 ...
- retry #3 connect timeout
- retry #5 never happen
- download failed at END (71 sec)

Comment: Awesome picture. To get the reader going faster, a bit of text walking through the example would be helpful. Regardless, a little patience proves useful here.